# Querying Grails domain class results in Hibernate QueryException

Tags: hibernate, grails

i have problem when excuting this code  org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

```
def show = {
    def results = PM.createCriteria().list() {
        eq("id_car_info", params.id.toLong())
    }
    def vehicleInfoInstance = VehicleInfo.get(params.id)
    if (!vehicleInfoInstance) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'vehicleInfo.label', default: 'VehicleInfo'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    } else {
        [vehicleInfoInstance: vehicleInfoInstance, results:results]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change title 'grails and spring source' to something more useful. And provide exact error message. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The domain class you are querying (with the weird name `PM`) does not have a property `id_car_info`. That's what Hibernate is telling you with it's exception.

*Please remember to provide more code and the full exception when posting on StackOverflow. It helps others to find a solution for their own problem and makes it easier to provide you with a better answer.*